# How to store index values using dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr, max

The data (dat) I have collected has 2 different buckets all part of the same set ("Set") filled with random number of marbles ("Marbles")
There are 2 treatments, "Color" (Blue/White) and "Size" (Small/Large). Each trial was done in different "Blocks" (ie. time slot). The 2 buckets were all part of one set. The position of the buckets are noted ("Position"). Here is a sample of the data.

```
Colour Set Size    Position  Marbles Block
Blue     1   Small  1         8     1
Blue     1   Small  2         81    1
Blue     6   Small  1         14    2
Blue     6   Small  2         11    2
Blue     1   Large  4         0     1
Blue     1   Large  5         0     1
Blue     1   Large  1         3     1
Blue     1   Large  2         43    1
White    1   Small  1         8     1
White    1   Small  2         81    1
White    1   Small  6         7     1
White    6   Small  3         12    2
White    6   Small  4         25    2
White    2   Large  1         86    1
White    2   Large  2         77    1
White    1   Large  1         3     11
White    1   Large  2         43    11
```

For each unique replicate (i.e. unique combination of color, set, block, size), I want to find index position of the max value of marbles.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
a <- vector()
result <- dat %>% 
  mutate(MaxMarbles = max(dat$marbles)) %>% 
  group_by(colour, size, block, set) %>% 
  pos1 <- which(a == max(dat$marbles))
```

I keep running into an error that says could not find "%>%". I verified the installation of dplyr and ensured that it is called from the library. However, I am unable to detect the problem and was wondering perhaps its a syntax error that I'm unable to catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule: **Never *ever* load plyr after dplyr** :)

Now to the question. This will get you the indices of rows that have the maximum number of marbles within their group:

```
library(dplyr)
result_df <- dat %>% 
  group_by(colour, size, block, set) %>%
  mutate(result = (marbles == max(marbles)))
result_vec <- which(result_df$result)
```

If you want boolean indices you can omit the `which()`.

Comment: You should actually just move away from `plyr` completely and use `dplyr`. You don't know how much time I've wasted because of this...

Comment: Thanks. I see that I was using the mutate function incorrectly. That solved it. Also, noted - will only be using dplyr from now on